# Command set for redis takes forever

Tags: python, flask, redis, debian

I am trying to use pyredis in my flask application.

I have the following python code:

```
r_server = Redis()
p = r_server.pipeline()                 

r_server.set('test_key', 'testdsokdksodksdoe')                       
print 'previous set key ' + r_server.get('test_key')
p.execute()
```

And the redis-server is logging the following:

```
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:38.537 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:38.537 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:43.550 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:43.551 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:48.564 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:48.564 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:53.576 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:53.576 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:58.586 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:15:58.586 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:03.597 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:03.598 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:08.609 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:08.609 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:13.621 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:13.621 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:18.633 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:18.634 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:23.648 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:23.648 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:28.662 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:28.662 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 366680 bytes in use
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:30.521 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:48944
[19083] 03 Dec 21:16:30.522 - Client closed connection
```

So you can see it takes almost a minute to set the key. Why is it so?

I am running Debian Wheezy.
Redis version is: 2.8.17

Comment: Is that Python code executed in some sort of loop?

Comment: No, in a flask view.

Comment: Two suggestions:
1) Use redis-py, not pyredis. It's much more mature.
2) Try disabling pipelining and see what happens.

Comment: Will give it a try. I use memcache for now.